# В nuxt 3 ошибка при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть список с карточками, при нажатии на которую, в момент перехода на новую страницу, появляется ошибка, вот на этой строчке

```
<NuxtLink :to="'/page/' + item.slug" class="cards__item">
```

О том, что item null
Card.vue:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slug')
at Proxy._sfc_render (Card.vue:6:37)

Т.е оно в момент перехода очищает переменную list и появляется ошибка или из-за чего это?

Вот код:

```
<script setup>
        const {  list } = defineProps(['list'])
    </script>
    
    <template>
        <div class="cards">
            <Card v-for="item in list" :item="item" />
        </div>
    </template>
```

....

```
<script setup>
    const {  item } = defineProps(['item'])
    </script>
    
    <template>
        <NuxtLink :to="'/page/' + item.slug" class="cards__item">
            123
        </NuxtLink>
    </template>
```